Loadrunner error on replay after using parameters
i'm doing some recording tests with the Advantage online shopping website, managed to record the process to login, add a product to the shopping cart and checkout, problem is, whenever I change the username and password to a parameter, it stops working, posting the blocks where I changed the username and password to parameters since spam filter doesn't allow that many url
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "AUTO");
    
    web_set_user(lr_eval_string("{Usuario}"), 
             lr_eval_string("{Password}"),
        "www.advantageonlineshopping.com:443");

    web_custom_request("AccountLoginRequest_3", 
        "URL=", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/xml", 
        "Referer=https://www.advantageonlineshopping.com/", 
        "Snapshot=t75.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=text/xml; charset=UTF-8", 
        "Body=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><AccountLoginRequest xmlns=\"com.advantage.online.store.accountservice\"><email></email><loginPassword>{Password}</loginPassword><loginUser>{Usuario}</loginUser></AccountLoginRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", 
        LAST);

    web_set_sockets_option("INITIAL_AUTH", "BASIC");

    web_url("907992560_11", 
        "URL=https://www.advantageonlineshopping.com/order/api/v1/carts/907992560", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://www.advantageonlineshopping.com/", 
        "Snapshot=t76.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);

then I get this error whenever I try to replay it
Login.c(128): Error -26611: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "https://www.advantageonlineshopping.com/order/api/v1/carts/907992560"    [MsgId: MERR-26611]
and whenever I double click it, it goes to the last block of the script(the  web_url("907992560_11" one), any idea why this happens?
Tried with and without parameters, without them the recording works and i can replay it, with them, i just keep getting the same error, tried commenting the block of code that gives error and i get another error with a different block in the next action

Record it twice with the same credentials.  Compare the scripts.  You will find the items related to session and state.
Record with a different userID and you will find the items related to credentials.
I see what appears to be a number of unhandled dynamic elements that would lead to a 5xx error message if not addressed.
Note:  To use this tool you need training.  Your Management also owes you a mentor for a period of time.  If they have denied you either, then seek a new employer - your management is only interested in billing and not value.  They will sacrifice you to save a customer relationship

hi! thanks for the answer!, i'm actually in training and we were asked to find this on our own, fixed it by making a correlation to the userid generated whenever i logged in, turns out the web_set_user wasn't working so i had to do it manually
